# What file format does Deus Ex HR use for it's level data?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm wanting to export some of the Deus Ex HR levels into another program and combine them to create a virtual city to walk around in, and eventually add NPCs, ect...

I only plan on using this for a personal project, and not to redistribute.

I have it on PS3 and Xbox 360, but I don't want to buy it on PC until I know if this kind of thing would be possible, or at least know what file format the game uses for it's levels.

I'm not concerned about keeping any of the interactivity or clipping data just the layouts and textures.

This basically just stems from a deep love of the virtual world the developers have created, and I'd like to continue that world with some of my own touches.

I'm not concerned what 3D program can handle the levels either, as I have most through my work.

**To sum up: What file format does Deus Ex HR use for it's level data, and can anyone point me in the direction of this kind of thing being done with other games.**

Answer (score 1):

Since modeling and the related artwork comprises a large quantity of work, especially for a high quality modern game, and the fact that these could be very valuable assets in the hands of a competent and rival development team, these files tend to be secured heavily (meaning custom storage and representation formats, possibly encryption too). I don't expect that there would be any way to extract them with less work than it would take to recreate all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should browse through the XeNTaX forum.
http://forum.xentax.com/

Take a look at thread called "BIGFILE.000 - Deus Ex Human Revolution Unpack".
http://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=7208

You could also try this one if you'd like to compile the tool by yourself: https://github.com/LazyBui/gibbedtr

Somewhere within the thread there is binary file of latest version available for download. Can't remember exact page, now. It would be wise to read everything anyway. That version worked fine with mine DXHR Director's Cut bought on Steam but should work for other platforms as well (again, read the thread).

Just note that after unpacking the files you won't get files in common formats (i.e. no JPG or PNG for textures). You will have to learn more about engine's file types and how to read them.